# Finding a point that always cuts a polygon into halfs of similar size

Tags: polygons, discrete-geometry

I've been trying to solve this problem:

Let $P\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ be a closed polygon with area $A(P)$, not necessarily convex. Prove that there is a point $x\in\mathbb{R}^2$ such that every line that contains $x$ divides $P$ into two parts, each with area at least $\frac{A(P)}{3}$.

My only idea so far was to use the Shoelace formula, and possibly the Centerpoint theorem  to find this point, but nothing has given me the wanted result. I'm not sure what I can use to show this.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions on how to approach this.

Comment: Just copy the proof of the Centerpoint Theorem.

Comment: It doesn't strike me as being likely to be true.  I would consider an extreme example of a non-convex polygon, a horseshoe for example.

Comment: @MishaLavrov I have run into this problem and I am not sure if my solution is correct so I would like to check without opening a new question. My idea is to emulate the centerpoint thm proof on open halfspaces $\gamma$ such that $S(\gamma \cap P) > 2/3S(P)$. Now we would consider $C(\gamma \cap \cap P)$'s. Every three will intersect because of the area condition and we can apply Helly theorem. Finally to check that a point $x$ in intersection works we assume it doesn't and we can get a contradiction. Is my proof the idea you had in mind?

Comment: @TdotA Probably? It's been nearly a year. Looking at your idea, it should work, although a hypothesis we need here that we got automatically in the case of a finite set of points is that $P$ needs to be bounded, because Helly's theorem needs compact sets - we can get compactness by taking a large ball $B$ containing $P$ and replacing each half-space by its intersection with $B$. (I haven't carefully thought this through, though, so maybe you're better off opening a new question to confirm any details you feel unsure of.)

Comment: @MishaLavrov I thought that would be in bad taste as a question has already been asked. I implicitly assumed P was bounded as otherwise S(P) would br infinite so S(P)/3 wouldn't be usegul I assume? Anyway, I will open a new question.

Comment: @TdotA I think it's fine in your case as this question has not been answered, *and* you have a specific approach in mind. (The word "polygon" does suggest $P$ is bounded, actually; I was worried at first about weird unbounded shapes with finite area like the region $\{(x,y) : x \ge 0 \text{ and } 0 \le y \le e^{-x}\}$.)

Comment: @MishaLavrov, I ended up finding a mistake in my approach, mainly if we work with closed halfspaces their complements are open. Thus the contradiction in the end doesn't work. Thought you might be mildly interested in that.